# Laravel : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I have three tables (services, services_products, services_product_translation)

when try to insert new product I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'services_products.services_product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `services_products` where `services_products`.`services_product_id` = 3)

here is my migrations
services migration

```
Schema::create('services', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->binary('image');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

services_products migration

```
Schema::create('services_products', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('service_id')->unsigned();
            $table->binary('image');
            $table->binary('pdf');

            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and this is the translation table

```
Schema::create('services_product_translations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title', 150);
            $table->longText('details');
            $table->string('locale')->index();

            $table->unique(['product_id', 'locale']);
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('services_products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

and this is my models

Service

```
class Service extends \Eloquent
{

    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'brief'];
    public $translationModel = 'ServicesTranslation';

    public function servicesPro()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ServicesProduct', 'service_id');
    }
}
```

ServicesProduct

```
class ServicesProduct extends \Eloquent
{
    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'details'];
    public $translationModel = 'ServicesProductTranslation';


    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Service', 'service_id');
    }

    public function proImage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ServicesProductImage', 'image_id');
    }

    public function proVideo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ServicesProductVideo', 'video_id');
    }
```

and this is my controller I used to store

```
public function store()
    {
        $sev_id = Input::get('category');
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $pdf = Input::file('pdf');

        $destination_path = 'images/servicesProductsImages/';
        $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destination_path, $filename);

        $destination_path_pdf = 'images/servicesProductsPdf/';
        $filenamePdf = str_random(6) . '_' . $pdf->getClientOriginalName();
        $pdf->move($destination_path_pdf, $filenamePdf);


        $newSerPro = new ServicesProduct();

        $newSerPro->service_id = $sev_id;
        $newSerPro->image = $filename;
        $newSerPro->pdf = $filenamePdf;
        $newSerPro->save();

        $localization = Input::get('localization');
        $locales = array_keys($localization);
        foreach ($locales as $locale) {
            if (!in_array($locale, array('en', 'ar'))) {
                Session::flash('message', 'Lang Error');
                return Redirect::to('admin/create-service-sub-category');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Should it only be "services_products.id"? I did not see the field you mentioned in your migration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, there is no column with name `services_product_id` present in `services_products` table. That's why it is showing the error.

I think the column name in condition is like `services_products.id` because generally we join table on there primary column and its primary column is `id`

Answer (score 1):

Posting my comment as answer:

> Should it only be "services_products.id"? I did not see the field you
>   mentioned in your migration.